# Percentile calculator

Tags: scala, percentile

I have been trying to create a small method to calculate given percentile from a seq. It works.. almost. Problem is I don't know why is doesn't work. I was hoping one of your 'a bit smarter' people than me could help me with it.

What I hope the result would be is that it would return the item from the seq that n prosent of the seq is smaller than equal than returned value.

```
def percentile[Int](p: Int)(seq: Seq[Int]) = {
  require(0 <= p && p <= 100)                      // some value requirements
  require(!seq.isEmpty)                            // more value requirements
  val sorted = seq.sorted
  val k = math.ceil((seq.length - 1) * (p / 100)).toInt
  return sorted(k)
}
```

So for example if I have

```
val v = Vector(7, 34, 39, 18, 16, 17, 21, 36, 17, 2, 4, 39, 4, 19, 2, 12, 35, 13, 40, 37)
```

and I call my function `percentile(11)(v)` return value is 2. However, 10% of the vector are smaller or equal than 2, not 11% like I am calling. `percentile(11)(v)` should return 4.

Comment: what do you mean by "it works almost... it doesn't work" ? Is this supposed to be a puzzle ? if you are encountering an error, please provide the error !

Comment: no errors but return is sometimes incorrect

Answer (score 6):

your error is in this row:

```
 val k = math.ceil((seq.length - 1) * (p / 100)).toInt
```

and particularly here: `p / 100`. Being `p` an Int <= 100 and >= 0, `p/100` will always be equal to 0 or 1 (if `p == 100`). If you want a floating point result, you have to widen one of the two values to double: `p/100.0`

```
 val k = math.ceil((seq.length - 1) * (p / 100.0)).toInt
```

On a side note: you don't need the `[Int]` type parameter

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with the part `p / 100` in

```
val k = math.ceil((seq.length - 1) * (p / 100)).toInt
```

Since `p` is of type `Int` and `100` is also an `Int`, the division is an integer division that returns an `Int`. If either `p` or `100` is a `Double`, the result will be a `Double`.

The easiest fix would be to change that part in `p / 100.0`.