# Spark computing percentile on a cell containing a list of doubles

Tags: scala, apache-spark, arraylist, percentile

I have a DataFrame that has a column of cells containing a list of doubles. Here is an example:

```
 c1      c2      c3
-------------------------------------------

 a       a       [0.0,1.0, 6.0,3.3 ...]

 a       b       [1.0, 2.0, 3.4, ... ]

 aa      c       [1.0, 2.2, 3.5, ... ]

 ...
```

This DataFrame was generated by reading in multiple CSV files, which then were passed through `collect_list` as well as `sort_array`. For example:

```
val df = orig.groupBy ("c1","c2").agg( sort_array(collect_list("c3")).as("c3") )
```

For each cell in column 3 (c3), I would like to compute the percentile over each cell. The resulting DataFrame would contain only a single value in c3.

I would appreciate any pointers to this matter.

Comment: what do you mean by percentile over each cell? can you share the logic?

Comment: Hi Ramesh,   something like: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36479891/percentile-calculator

Answer (score 1):

Following seem to have done the trick.  Note that the correctness of the function is not really relevant here, but rather, how it was invoked:

```
def computePercentile(data: WrappedArray [Double], tile: Int): Double ={ ... }


val test = orig.select("c3").rdd.map { case Row { val:WrappedArray[Double]) => (val,computePercentile (val,95))}.toDF("c1percent")
```

A second approach was a variation using a UDF.

```
val percentUDF = org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf((val: WrappedArray[Double]) => {computePercentile(simval,95)})
...

val result = orig.groupBy ("c1","c2").agg(percentUDF(sort_array(collect_list("c3"))).as("c3"))
```

The resulting table is what I wanted:

```
c1      c2      c3
------------------------------

 a       a       0.111

 a       b       0.222

 aa      c       1.123
```